# ASP.NET.MVC 5 How can i display information about who created an element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Created an app with Windows Authentication.
I need an advice from you about how can i display information about who is creater (or modified by) of an element and when was it(or when it waas changed) ?

My model is

```
  Public class Movie

    {

    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Text{get;set;}

    public datetime Created{get;set;}

    public string CreatedBy {get;set;}

    public datetime Modified{get;set;}

    public string ModifiedBy {get;set;}           
    }
```

And controller is

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Movies/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Text,Created,CreatedBy,Modified,ModifiedBy")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Movies.Add(movie);

                  db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(movie);
        }
```

Comment: Those values should not be part of the view/form - you set them in the POST method immediately before you save the record

Comment: Here is a complete working solution exctly for your case:  https://benjii.me/2014/03/track-created-and-modified-fields-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first/

Comment: take the username of user from logged in session, and insert it into your fields

Comment: I should write without "set" u mean ? public datetime Created{get;}

Comment: thanks for the link, i created app with windows authentication btw

Comment: @whitefang does not matter what type of authentication, as long as there is `HttpContext.Current.User` value set.

Comment: Here is another very similar solution: https://blogs.infosupport.com/tracking-creation-and-modification-data-with-ado-net-entity-framework/ and another one: https://betechnical.blog/2016/06/07/handle-createddatemodifieddatecreatedby-and-modifiedby-in-entity-framework/ and one more: https://www.altitudesystems.co.uk/entity-framework-audit-fields

Comment: @whitefang "I should write without "set" u mean"...no because the you can't populate your values from the database easily when you want to display them. However, they should only be part of the ViewModel for _displaying_ movies, they should not be part of the ViewModel for _creating_ movies, because they are not user-updatable values...

Comment: ...The system controls these values - the server should set them directly on the Entity-Framework movie object during the Create POST method (using HttpContext.Current.User and DateTime.Now) before you save it to the database. Right now you seem to be using your EF entity as the ViewModel, but this is not sustainable in this case - you need two separate ViewModel classes, and then you map from a viewModel onto the EF object for saving, and back again to the other viewmodel for displaying (tools like AutoMapper can make this less tedious, btw) - that's the recommended pattern in MVC in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your Create action as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Movies/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Text")] Movie movie)
    {
        movie.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Current.User;
        movie.Created = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movie);

              db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

Implement the same for Edit action as done for Create action.
Hope helps!

Comment: why are you included the Created and Modified dates in the Movie model still? These should not be updatable by the client...the server should set them when it saves to the database. Otherwise a user could fake the value if they wanted to.

Comment: Also no need to store user info in the session like that - `HttpContext.Current.User` will always contain the user info when they are logged in. And certainly in Windows Auth there is no separate user ID and username either, just the username.

Comment: Your are absolutely right. I left this to the questioner. Though, let me edit it..

Comment: you still don't need a separate class for the user info, or need to store it in the session. .NET does all that for you already

Comment: Mr. @ADyson; Done! )))

Comment: i get an error Error CS1061 'HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Use as `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User`

Comment: Do i need to downloand some nugets?

Comment: if i use that   movie.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Profile.UserName; ?

Comment: Not sure, actually I use different (custom) authentications. Never liked that .Net does these things for me ))

Comment: if i use system.web.httpcontext.current.user he is giving me an error " the type name "current" does not exist in the type 'httpcontext'

Comment: Zhavat is your working ? I can't create an element after this changes.

Comment: If you are getting an error for `Current` with `HttpContext` you should find out that first. I have no problems with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User`